# Design pattern for cancelling or ignoring obsolete task on a worker thread

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, atl

I apologize if there's an obvious answer to this, but I just haven't located it yet.

I'm creating an application that loads some information from a database when the user navigates into an Explorer directory.  I'm doing this on a background worker thread (using ATL's `CWorkerThread`), and calling `SetEvent` when the navigation occurs. When the background thread is done loading the data, it posts a custom message to a message-only window back on the UI thread. Then the UI thread can do stuff with the loaded info if it wants.

Of course, if the user navigates into a directory, and the worker-thread starts working, but the user quickly navigates away, the current worker-thread task is no longer necessary.  So the task should be either cancelled if in progress, or if the worker thread has already posted its completion message to the UI thread, the UI thread should be prepared to check it and ignore it, since it's now stale.

My question is whether there is a nice design pattern and helpful example for this type of situation.  I think I've seen situations in which a looping worker thread checks a boolean (like `fCancelled`) to see if it should still continue doing something. But how about when the completion message is already posted?  Is there any standard way in which the worker thread and UI thread can communicate that the message is stale and should be disregarded?

Thank you very much for any input.

Comment: This isn't actually about design patterns as much as it is about platform constraints. Since you cannot safely terminate a thread from the outside, you'll have to build cancellation support into your worker thread.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to actually terminate a thread--I just want to gracefully stop or ignore the task that the thread has done (before it goes back to `WaitForMultipleObjects`).

Comment: There are only two ways to stop a thread from doing work: Terminate the thread, or make the thread stop doing work. The former cannot be done safely, so you'll need to do the latter. And that requires coöperation from within the thread, hence you're going to have to implement cancellation support into the worker thread. That can be done any way that suits your needs, such as regularly evaluating the termination condition.